# Include multiple tables with EntityFramework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, linq

I have 3 tables like below image

[image: Tables]

And I have the entity framework codefirst model on the c# (Auto generated)

I'm trying to get the IEnumerable from entities with included Attachments list of each element and I want those attachments elements included with AttachmentType for each Attachments.

for better demonstration I need:

```
IEnumerable<Registry> registries = GetTableData();
string oneofthedesiredname = registries
.First()
.Attachments
.First()
.AttachmentType.Name; //I want that, this definition works but its null
```

with GetTableData() method is like

```
public IEnumerable<Registry> GetTableData()
    {
        IQueryable<Registry> _registries = _entities.Registry;
        IEnumerable<Registry> data;
        data = _registries
        .Where(p=>p.IsDeleted==false)
        .Include(p=>p.Attachments.Where(x=>x.IsDeleted==false))
        .AsEnumerable();//this query should have change because I cant get Attachmenttypes from this            
        return data;
    }
```

Thank you all, your helps are appreciated.

Comment: Maybe I'm blind but I cannot find a way to get from Rgistries to Attachments for only Attachments knows about Registries. Could you please post your EF code models?

Answer (score 0):

You must add extra Include for AttachmentType also in the query.

```
public IEnumerable<Registry> GetTableData()
{
    IQueryable<Registry> _registries = _entities.Registry;

    IEnumerable<Registry> data = _registries
        .Include(x => x.Attachments)
        .Include("Attachments.AttachmentType")
         // here do necessary filtering with Where()
         // ...

    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**use this funcation**

```
public IEnumerable<Registry> GetTableData()
    {
        IQueryable<Registry> _registries = _entities.Registry,where(m=>m.IsDeleted==false);
        IEnumerable<Registry> data;
        data = _registries     .Include(p=>p.Attachments.Where(x=>x.IsDeleted==false)).
 include(p=>p.AttachmentType).AsEnumerable();
        return data;
    }
```